# Convert string in an a tuple into an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to convert the second item in each tuple into an integer so that I will be able to add up all the values in the row.

```
compPoss = [(('A', '1'), ('B','2'), ('C', '3'), ('D', '4')), 
            (('A', '1'), ('B','2'), ('C', '3'), ('E', '5'))]

totRank = sum(n for _, n in compPoss)
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'

Tried different methods to work this out but I keep getting error codes

Outcome should be

> 10
>
> 11

Answer (score 2):

Your code is almost correct, you just don't take account of the fact that your list is a list of tuples of tuples, so you need to unpack it twice. Then in your `sum` you need to convert `n` into an integer to allow it to be summed:

```
compPoss = [(('A', '1'), ('B','2'), ('C', '3'), ('D', '4')), 
            (('A', '1'), ('B','2'), ('C', '3'), ('E', '5'))]

totRank = [sum(int(n) for _, n in a) for a in compPoss]
print(totRank)
```

Output

```
[10, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
tuple_list = [(('A', '1'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '3'), ('D', '4')), 
              (('A', '1'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '3'), ('E', '5'))]


# iterate over each row:
for row in tuple_list:

    # initialize variables:
    row_sum = 0

    # iterate over each point (tuple):
    for point in row:

        # convert number to int:
        number = int(point[1])

        # add to sum:
        row_sum += number

    # print row sum:
    print(row_sum)
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you so much, I spent the last two hours trying to figure this out. God Bless You.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
for t in tuple_list:
    print(sum(map(int,list(zip(*t))[1])))
```

---

output

```
10
11
```

You can write the above in using **list comprehension**.

```
res=[sum(map(int,list(zip(*t))[1])) for t in tuple_list]
print(res)
#[10,11]
```